# Numpy meshgrid in 3D

Tags: python, numpy

Numpy's meshgrid is very useful for converting two vectors to a coordinate grid. What is the easiest way to extend this to three dimensions? So given three vectors x, y, and z, construct 3x3D arrays (instead of 2x2D arrays) which can be used as coordinates.

Comment: As of 2023 it works for any number of dimensions, so `np.meshgrid(x, y, z)`.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Here is the source code of meshgrid:

```
def meshgrid(x,y):
    """
    Return coordinate matrices from two coordinate vectors.

    Parameters
    ----------
    x, y : ndarray
        Two 1-D arrays representing the x and y coordinates of a grid.

    Returns
    -------
    X, Y : ndarray
        For vectors `x`, `y` with lengths ``Nx=len(x)`` and ``Ny=len(y)``,
        return `X`, `Y` where `X` and `Y` are ``(Ny, Nx)`` shaped arrays
        with the elements of `x` and y repeated to fill the matrix along
        the first dimension for `x`, the second for `y`.

    See Also
    --------
    index_tricks.mgrid : Construct a multi-dimensional "meshgrid"
                         using indexing notation.
    index_tricks.ogrid : Construct an open multi-dimensional "meshgrid"
                         using indexing notation.

    Examples
    --------
    >>> X, Y = np.meshgrid([1,2,3], [4,5,6,7])
    >>> X
    array([[1, 2, 3],
           [1, 2, 3],
           [1, 2, 3],
           [1, 2, 3]])
    >>> Y
    array([[4, 4, 4],
           [5, 5, 5],
           [6, 6, 6],
           [7, 7, 7]])

    `meshgrid` is very useful to evaluate functions on a grid.

    >>> x = np.arange(-5, 5, 0.1)
    >>> y = np.arange(-5, 5, 0.1)
    >>> xx, yy = np.meshgrid(x, y)
    >>> z = np.sin(xx**2+yy**2)/(xx**2+yy**2)

    """
    x = asarray(x)
    y = asarray(y)
    numRows, numCols = len(y), len(x)  # yes, reversed
    x = x.reshape(1,numCols)
    X = x.repeat(numRows, axis=0)

    y = y.reshape(numRows,1)
    Y = y.repeat(numCols, axis=1)
    return X, Y
```

It is fairly simple to understand.  I extended the pattern to an arbitrary number of dimensions, but this code is by no means optimized (and not thoroughly error-checked either), but you get what you pay for.  Hope it helps:

```
def meshgrid2(*arrs):
    arrs = tuple(reversed(arrs))  #edit
    lens = map(len, arrs)
    dim = len(arrs)

    sz = 1
    for s in lens:
        sz*=s

    ans = []    
    for i, arr in enumerate(arrs):
        slc = [1]*dim
        slc[i] = lens[i]
        arr2 = asarray(arr).reshape(slc)
        for j, sz in enumerate(lens):
            if j!=i:
                arr2 = arr2.repeat(sz, axis=j) 
        ans.append(arr2)

    return tuple(ans)
```

Comment: In the case of a 3d mesh-grid, using a sample like the one provided in numpy doc for meshgrib, this would return Z,Y,X instead of X,Y,Z.  

Replacing the return statement by `return tuple(ans[::-1])` can fix this.

Comment: @Paul if the length of x or y array are long then x.repeat() command crashes and sends Memory Error. Is there any way to avoid this error?

Comment: @Dalek How long are the arrays? Could it be that you run out of memory? For example, if there are 3 arrays, 4096 entries each, and each entry holds a double (i.e. 8bytes), then for entries alone we need (8 * 4 * 2**10)**3 bytes = 2**45 bytes = 32 * 2**40 bytes = 32 TB of memory, which is obviously enourmous. I hope I have not made a mistake here.

Answer (score 85):

Numpy (as of 1.8 I think) now supports higher that 2D generation of position grids with [meshgrid](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.meshgrid.html). One important addition which really helped me is the ability to chose the indexing order (either `xy` or `ij` for Cartesian or matrix indexing respectively), which I verified with the following example:

```
import numpy as np

x_ = np.linspace(0., 1., 10)
y_ = np.linspace(1., 2., 20)
z_ = np.linspace(3., 4., 30)

x, y, z = np.meshgrid(x_, y_, z_, indexing='ij')

assert np.all(x[:,0,0] == x_)
assert np.all(y[0,:,0] == y_)
assert np.all(z[0,0,:] == z_)
```

Comment: What does the assert do? Why is it necessary to be there?

Comment: `assert` is just a check that indexing along x, y and z axis equal the expected *_ variable. No need.

Answer (score 7):

Can you show us how you are using np.meshgrid? There is a very good chance that you really don't need meshgrid because numpy broadcasting can do the same thing without generating a repetitive array.

For example,

```
import numpy as np

x=np.arange(2)
y=np.arange(3)
[X,Y] = np.meshgrid(x,y)
S=X+Y

print(S.shape)
# (3, 2)
# Note that meshgrid associates y with the 0-axis, and x with the 1-axis.

print(S)
# [[0 1]
#  [1 2]
#  [2 3]]

s=np.empty((3,2))
print(s.shape)
# (3, 2)

# x.shape is (2,).
# y.shape is (3,).
# x's shape is broadcasted to (3,2)
# y varies along the 0-axis, so to get its shape broadcasted, we first upgrade it to
# have shape (3,1), using np.newaxis. Arrays of shape (3,1) can be broadcasted to
# arrays of shape (3,2).
s=x+y[:,np.newaxis]
print(s)
# [[0 1]
#  [1 2]
#  [2 3]]
```

The point is that `S=X+Y` can and should be replaced by `s=x+y[:,np.newaxis]` because 
the latter does not require (possibly large) repetitive arrays to be formed. It also generalizes to higher dimensions (more axes) easily. You just add `np.newaxis` where needed to effect broadcasting as necessary.

See http://www.scipy.org/EricsBroadcastingDoc for more on numpy broadcasting.

Answer (score 6):

i think what you want is

```
X, Y, Z = numpy.mgrid[-10:10:100j, -10:10:100j, -10:10:100j]
```

for example.

Comment: Thanks, but this is not quite what I need - meshgrid actually uses the values of the vectors to generate the 2D array, and the values can be irregularly spaced.

Answer (score 4):

Instead of writing a new function, [numpy.ix_](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ix_.html) should do what you want.

Here is an example from the documentation:

```
>>> ixgrid = np.ix_([0,1], [2,4])
>>> ixgrid
(array([[0],
   [1]]), array([[2, 4]]))
>>> ixgrid[0].shape, ixgrid[1].shape
((2, 1), (1, 2))'
```

Answer (score 4):

Here is a multidimensional version of meshgrid that I wrote:

```
def ndmesh(*args):
   args = map(np.asarray,args)
   return np.broadcast_arrays(*[x[(slice(None),)+(None,)*i] for i, x in enumerate(args)])
```

Note that the returned arrays are views of the original array data, so changing the original arrays will affect the coordinate arrays.

Answer (score -2):

You can achieve that by changing the order:

```py
import numpy as np
xx = np.array([1,2,3,4])
yy = np.array([5,6,7])
zz = np.array([9,10])
y, z, x = np.meshgrid(yy, zz, xx)
```