# MATLAB's griddata3 for NumPy?

Tags: python, numpy, analysis, interpolation, scientific-computing

I realize that there is a griddata for [NumPy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NumPy) via [Matplotlib](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matplotlib), but is there a griddata3 (same has griddata, but for higher dimensions)?

In other words, I have (x,y,z,d(x,y,z)) where (x,y,z) form an irregular grid and d(x,y,z) is a scalar function of three variables. I need to generate d(xi, yi, zi) for a new set of (xi, yi, zi) points using some kind of interpolation that can handle the non-uniformity of the original (x,y,z) data.

Ultimately, the (xi, yi, zi, d(xi, yi, zi)) data will have to be rendered as a surface somehow, but that's a problem for later. I also do not have an analytical form for the d(.) function; I just have data for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[SciPy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SciPy) 0.9 (at the moment, a first beta is out) has a new [griddata](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.griddata.html) function that can handle N-dimensional data.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure how you intend to render a surface of a scalar function of 3 variables, except perhaps using cutplanes or something similar. [Mayavi](http://code.enthought.com/projects/mayavi/) (really [VTK](http://www.vtk.org/) which powers Mayavi) has support for efficient Delaunay triangulation via `enthought.mayavi.mlab.pipeline.delaunay3d`, which is the core of the algorithm used by `griddata3`. See [the 2D example](http://code.enthought.com/projects/mayavi/docs/development/html/mayavi/auto/example_surface_from_irregular_data.html#example-surface-from-irregular-data) code they have posted, just add one dimension (and use `delaunay3d` instead). I don't know of a way to explicitly get the interpolated values used to render the surface, but there might be a way to sample it through Mayavi, you could dig through the documentation or ask on one of the Enthought mailing lists.

Alternatively, one of the C functions in the NCAR [natgrid](http://www.ncl.ucar.edu/Document/Functions/Built-in/natgrid.shtml) library may be useful i.e. [dsgrid3d](http://www.ncl.ucar.edu/Document/Functions/Built-in/dsgrid3d.shtml). There is a partial wrapper implemented as a [matplotlib toolkit](http://sourceforge.net/projects/matplotlib/files/matplotlib-toolkits/natgrid-0.1).

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with griddata3, but you might want to look into [meshgrid](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.meshgrid.html) and this related [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1827489/numpy-meshgrid-in-3d/1830192#1830192).