# matplotlib wireframe plot / 3d plot howTo

Tags: python, 3d, plot, matplotlib, wireframe

I would like to have a 3d plot with matplotlib.

Data are the following: I have a matrix with each row containing Y coordinates for the 3d plot. Each row first elements are the X coordinates for the 3d plot. Finally, a second matrix contains high for each point, at a X,Y position. This second matrix thus contains my Z coordinates. Both matrices are arrays of arrays with Python. I would like to know how to transform data so as to obtain:

- a plot of each 1d signal corresponding to an X, like this (photo available online) [image]
- a wireframe plot for same data, like this [image]

I have written an helper function for a wireframe work,

```
 ########  HELPER FOR PLOT 3-D

 def plot_3d(name,X,Y,Z):

     fig = plt.figure(name)
     ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')
     X = np.array(X)
     Y = np.array(Y)
     Z = np.array(Z)
     ax.plot_wireframe(X,Y,Z,rstride=10,cstride=10)
     ax.set_xlabel('X Label')
     ax.set_ylabel('Y Label')
     plt.show()
```

but I dont know how to transform data X,Y,Z to make them fit requirements for matplotlib function, which want 2D lists for X, Y ,Z.

For first graph, I read help, and want to use 2d plot in 3d. Example source code gives:

```
x = np.linspace(0, 1, 100)
y = np.sin(x * 2 * np.pi) / 2 + 0.5
ax.plot(x, y, zs=0, zdir='z', label='zs=0, zdir=z')
```

where z is the constant coordinate. In my case, x is the constant coordinate. I adapt with

```
        fig = plt.figure('2d profiles')
        ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')
        for i in range(10):
             x = pt  ## this is a scalar
             y = np.array(y)
             z = np.array(z)
             ax.plot(xs = x, y, z, xdir='x')
        plt.show()
```

but there is warning: `non-keyword arg after keyword arg`. How to fix?

Thanks and regards

Comment: You mean an exception. Try changing the line `ax.plot(xs = x, y, z, xdir='x')` with `ax.plot(xs = x, ys-y, zs=z, xdir='x')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding the display of a serie of vectors in 3D, I came with following 'almost working' solution:

```
def visualizeSignals(self, imin, imax):

    times = self.time[imin:imax]
    nrows = (int)((times[(len(times)-1)] - times[0])/self.mod) + 1

    fig = plt.figure('2d profiles')
    ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')
    for i in range(nrows-1):
        x = self.mat1[i][0] + self.mod * i
        y = np.array(self.mat1T[i])
        z = np.array(self.mat2[i])
        ax.plot(y, z, zs = x, zdir='z')

    plt.show()
```

As for 2D surface or meshgrid plot, I come through using meshgrid. Note that you can reproduce a meshgrid by yourself once you know how a meshgrid is built. For more info on meshgrid, I refer to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1827489/numpy-meshgrid-in-3d).

Here is the code (cannot use it as such since it refers to class members, but you can build your code based on 3d plot methods from matplotlib I am using)

```
def visualize(self, imin, imax, typ_ = "wireframe"):
    """
    3d plot signal between imin and imax
    . typ_: type of plot, "wireframce", "surface"
    """

    times = self.retT[imin:imax]
    nrows = (int)((times[(len(times)-1)] - times[0])/self.mod) + 1

    self.modulate(imin, imax)

    fig = plt.figure('3d view')
    ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')

    x = []
    for i in range(nrows):
        x.append(self.matRetT[i][0] + self.mod * i)

    y = []
    for i in range(len(self.matRetT[0])):
        y.append(self.matRetT[0][i])
    y = y[:-1]


    X,Y = np.meshgrid(x,y)

    z = [tuple(self.matGC2D[i]) for i in range(len(self.matGC))] # matGC a matrix

    zzip = zip(*z)

    for i in range(len(z)):
        print len(z[i])

    if(typ_ == "wireframe"):
        ax.plot_wireframe(X,Y,zzip)
        plt.show()
    elif(typ_ == "contour"):
        cset = ax.contour(X, Y, zzip, zdir='z', offset=0)
        plt.show()
    elif(typ_ == "surf_contours"):
        surf = ax.plot_surface(X, Y, zzip, rstride=1, cstride=1, alpha=0.3)
        cset = ax.contour(X, Y, zzip, zdir='z', offset=-40)
        cset = ax.contour(X, Y, zzip, zdir='x', offset=-40)
        cset = ax.contour(X, Y, zzip, zdir='y', offset=-40)
        plt.show()
```