# Python, from matrix to array

Tags: python

I have a 3d matrix `grid_z0`, whose dimension are (let's say) 50x25x36. Each point of this matrix represents a cell. I would like to convert this matrix into a 1D array of size 50x25x36. I would also like to create 3 array of the same size showing the coordinate of the cell center. 
The array `cx`,`cy` and `cz` stores the coordinate of the cell center in one direction.

This example work but it rather slow, especially for large data set. Is there a way to make it faster?

```
data={"x":[],"y":[],"z":[],"rho":[]}

for i in arange(0,50):
  for j in arange(0,25):
    for k in arange(0,36):
      data["x"].append(cx[i])
      data["y"].append(cy[j])
      data["z"].append(cz[k])
      data["f"].append(grid_z0[i][j][k])
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should consider using [NumPy](http://docs.scipy.org).

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.random.rand(50,25,36) # Create a fake array
>>> print a.shape
(50, 25, 36)
>>> a.shape = -1 # Flatten the array in place
>>> print a.shape
(45000,)
```

When flattening your array, you're doing the equivalent of :

```
>>> b = []
>>> for i in range(a.shape[0]):
...     for j in range(a.shape[1]):
...         for k in range(a.shape[2]):
...             b.append(a[i,j,k])
```

That is, the last axis is parsed first, then the second, then the first.

Given your three 1D lists `cx`, `cy`, `cz` of length `N`, you can construct a 2D array with:

```
>>> centers = np.array([cx,cy,cz])
>>> print centers.shape
(3, N)
```

Comment: Thanks, but what's the order of the reshaped matrix? For instance the what's the index in the new array of a[11][12][13]?

Answer (score 2):

Use [Numpy](http://numpy.org/) for matrix/array manipulation.

```
# convert to 1D array :
grid_1d = np.asarray(grid_z0).ravel()
```

For the second question, you need a 3D meshgrid. See here for an exemple :
[Numpy meshgrid in 3D](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1827489/numpy-meshgrid-in-3d)