# matplotlib creating 2D arrays from 1D arrays - is there a nicer way?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matplotlib

I am trying to visualise some 3d data I have using matplotlibs contour plots, surface plots and wireframe plots.

my raw data is in the form of a numpy array with x,y and z each in their own column (e.g.):

| xs | ys | zs  |
|---|---|----|
| 1 | 1 | 3  |
| 2 | 1 | 4  |
| 3 | 1 | 2  |
| 4 | 1 | 3  |
| 5 | 1 | 5  |
| 1 | 2 | -1 |
| 2 | 2 | -1 |
| 3 | 2 | -2 |
| 4 | 2 | 2  |
| 5 | 2 | 7  |
| 1 | 3 | 5  |
| 2 | 3 | 2  |
| 3 | 3 | 3  |
| 4 | 3 | 2  |
| 5 | 3 | 3  |

Now some of the plotting functions just take the data in 1D arrays corresponding to my columns (xs,ys,zs). However, some require a 2D array (meshgrid) format. Is there an easy way to convert from the 3 1D arrays to the correct format of 3 2D arrays? I have tried using numpy.meshgrid and, whilst this works for creating the X and Y 2D arrays, I can't work out a nice way to create the corresponding Z 2D array. I have managed to do it by making a blank 2D array and filling it with the appropriate values for Z, but this isn't very nice. Is there a better way to create the Z 2D array?

Below is my attempt (which works). Is there a way to make the Z array without cycling through both X and Y?

```
def getMeshGrid(dataArray):
    """get 2d coordinate grid and Z values in meshgrid format. requires values in
    dataArray to have a rectangular region of x-y space covered uniformly"""
    xs = dataArray[:,0]
    ys = dataArray[:,1]
    xmin,xmax = xs.min(), xs.max()
    xstep = xs[xs!=xmin].min()-xmin
    ymin,ymax = ys.min(), ys.max()
    ystep = ys[ys!=ymin].min()-ymin
    X = numpy.arange(xmin, xmax+xstep, xstep)
    Y = numpy.arange(ymin, ymax+ystep, ystep)
    X,Y = numpy.meshgrid(X,Y)
    Z = numpy.zeros(X.shape)
    height, width = X.shape
    for i in range(0, height):
        for j in range(0,width):
            halfway = dataArray[dataArray[:,0]==X[i,j]] # finds all with that value of x
            row = halfway[halfway[:,1]==Y[i,j]] # finds y value 
            Z[i,j] = row[0,6]
    return X,Y,Z
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1827489/numpy-meshgrid-in-3d

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your data is like the one you gave in the example, you already have a mesh (you have a value of z for each pair (x,y)) and you only need to reshape the arrays:

```
cols = np.unique(xs).shape[0]
X = xs.reshape(-1, cols)
Y = ys.reshape(-1, cols)
Z = zs.reshape(-1, cols)
```

Comment: Thanks. This is much simpler. 

However, I had a further question/complication. What if the xs, ys aren't in a regular order? 

e.g. xs = [1,2,4,3,5,5,4,3,1,2....]




Then if you do the above and pass it to a matplotlib function it seems to try and connect points rather strangely. Is the solution here just to sort the table beforehand?

Comment: @user2175850 Answering your question... you will have to sort twice. First put your data in one 2-D array:  `a = np.vstack((xs,ys,zs)).T`, then sort in x: `a = a[np.argsort(a[:,0])]`, then in y: `a = a[np.argsort(a[:,1])]`, then get your sorted data back: `xs, ys, zs = a.T`

Comment: Thanks. Doing the two argsort consecutively did not work as one sort removed the effects of the previous one. I solved this using lexsort.  a= a[numpy.lexsort((a[:,0],a[:,1]))]. It now all works perfectly.